# PHP push a value to an array during recursive search

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

```
    $menus = [
        0 => [
            'id' => 'home',
            'title' => 'Home',
            'url' => '/display/home',
            'children' => [],
            'parent' => null
        ],
        1 => [
            'id' => 'nodes',
            'title' => 'Nodes',
            'url' => 'nodes/index',
            'children' => [
                0 => [
                    'id' => 'addNode',
                    'title' => 'Add Node',
                    'url' => '/nodes/add',
                    'children' => [],
                    'parent' => "nodes"
                ],
                1 => [
                    'id' => 'editNode',
                    'title' => 'Edit Node',
                    'url' => '/nodes/edit',
                    'children' => [],
                    'parent' => 'nodes'
                ],
                2 => [
                    'id' => 'deleteNode',
                    'title' => 'Delete Node',
                    'url' => '/nodes/delete',
                    'children' => [
                        0 => [
                            'id' => 'deleteMultipleNodes',
                            'title' => 'Delete Multiple Nodes',
                            'url' => '/nodes/deleteall',
                            'children' => [
                                0 => [
                                    'id' => 'deleteMultipleSelectedNodes',
                                    'title' => 'Delete Multiple Selected Nodes',
                                    'url' => '/nodes/deleteallselected',
                                    'children' => [],
                                    'parent' => 'deleteMultipleNodes'
                                ]
                            ],
                            'parent' => 'deleteNode'
                        ]
                    ],
                    'parent' => 'nodes'
                ]

            ],
            'parent' => null
        ]
    ];
```

Assuming I have this array. What i want is to recursively search this array for an **"id"** and if found push a new children to the children array of that element.

I've tried it via different ways, I've also tried to use **RecursiveArrayIterator** to traverse the array, but the problem is how can i push value to that index of the array when found while traversing.

For Example here is a code from one of my tries:

```
private function traverseArray($array)
{

    $child = [
        'id' => 'deleteMultipleNotSelectedNodes',
        'title' => 'Delete Multiple Not Selected Nodes',
        'url' => '/nodes/deletenotselected',
        'children' => [],
        'parent' => 'deleteMultipleNodes'
    ];
    foreach($array as $key=>$value)
    {
        if(is_array($value))
        {
            $this->traverseArray($value);
        }
        if($key == "id" && $value == "deleteMultipleNodes") 
        {
            array_push($array["children"], $child); // This part is confusing me, How to add the child on this index where the id is found. 
        }
    }
}
```

Any help on how to do such thing in an efficient way would save my days.

Comment: If you fixed `deleteMultipleNodes` in your search then you must know the index, so what confusing?

Comment: push this child on what index?

Comment: Its recursively drilling down and if it founds the ID I want to to push the child to that id's element. But i don't have the index

Comment: There is a `children`, do you want one more similar to that?

Comment: Yes i want another sibling of that children in its parent's children array.

Comment: you can store the last `id` every time, so you can use this id for the next child.

Comment: id does not gives me the index. I mean how to get to know that i have to add this child to $menus[1][0][1] index

Comment: can you please add the desire block? what you actually want to push and where to push?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111762/discussion-between-subhan-ahmed-and-frayne-konok).

Comment: In the element where id is "deleteNode" there exists one children named "deleteSelectedNodes", i want to add another child there.

Comment: the 2nd if wouldn't work because you have assignment instead of comparison

Comment: Sorry I've edited that was a typo.

Comment: I'm not getting the current index of the array when i reach to that id.

Comment: Just an argument pass by value / reference issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here it's how it would work without using $this and fixing bugs in comparing $value instead assigning anything to value.

Please note the difference with &$array and &$value, which are references, so it would change the original data instead of copying it into new variables.

```
<?php
$menus = [
        0 => [
            'id' => 'home',
            'title' => 'Home',
            'url' => '/display/home',
            'children' => [],
            'parent' => null
        ],
        1 => [
            'id' => 'nodes',
            'title' => 'Nodes',
            'url' => 'nodes/index',
            'children' => [
                0 => [
                    'id' => 'addNode',
                    'title' => 'Add Node',
                    'url' => '/nodes/add',
                    'children' => [],
                    'parent' => "nodes"
                ],
                1 => [
                    'id' => 'editNode',
                    'title' => 'Edit Node',
                    'url' => '/nodes/edit',
                    'children' => [],
                    'parent' => 'nodes'
                ],
                2 => [
                    'id' => 'deleteNode',
                    'title' => 'Delete Node',
                    'url' => '/nodes/delete',
                    'children' => [
                        0 => [
                            'id' => 'deleteMultipleNodes',
                            'title' => 'Delete Multiple Nodes',
                            'url' => '/nodes/deleteall',
                            'children' => [
                                0 => [
                                    'id' => 'deleteMultipleSelectedNodes',
                                    'title' => 'Delete Multiple Selected Nodes',
                                    'url' => '/nodes/deleteallselected',
                                    'children' => [],
                                    'parent' => 'deleteMultipleNodes'
                                ]
                            ],
                            'parent' => 'deleteNode'
                        ]
                    ],
                    'parent' => 'nodes'
                ]

            ],
            'parent' => null
        ]
    ];

function traverseArray(&$array)
{
    $child = [
        'id' => 'deleteMultipleNotSelectedNodes',
        'title' => 'Delete Multiple Not Selected Nodes',
        'url' => '/nodes/deletenotselected',
        'children' => [],
        'parent' => 'deleteMultipleNodes'
    ];
    foreach($array as $key=>&$value)
    {
        if(is_array($value))
        {
            traverseArray($value);
        }
        if($key == "id" && $value == "deleteMultipleNodes") 
        {
            array_push($array["children"], $child); 
        }
    }
}

echo "=== before \n";
var_export($menus);
echo "\n\n";
traverseArray($menus);
echo "=== after \n";
var_export($menus);
```

Comment: Wow That worked. Can you please explain what &$array would do actually.

Comment: Passing by reference http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Modifying array during foreach cycle
http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/12652/modifying-an-array-during-a-foreach-loop

Comment: using array_walk_recursive is more efficient?

Comment: Pass by reference was a new concept to me in PHP and it worked like a dream. Thank you so much.

Comment: At least reference my comment above :P